# C# Design Choice - COM object or just another class?

Tags: c#, c++, architecture, com

The existing software uses C++ to code the communication layer as a single object. Microsoft COM object is used to connect the communication object to the upper layer of the UI. It exposes interfaces using the COM object.

New software requires me to create a completely different communication object that is radically different from the existing communication object. I can either choose to code it in C# as a separate class or create another COM object and re-use some of the C++ code to create the object.

Being a C native, I want to hear your advices before making a decision on how this future software change should be made. I feel that if I create another COM object, it seems unnecessary as a C# class within the upper layer can handle it. But then I get to re-use some of the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use COM anymore. I have no idea what you're looking for but COM is only for interop scenarios Please clarify a little bit more by providing an example `use case` or `usage scenario` or something.

Comment: So the existing COM is a legacy software we ported over. New software is in C# (UI layer) and the communication layer is C++. Therefore, COM was chosen as we did not want to re-write the layer into C#. Now we need to add on to the communication layer with another communication protocol and I want to know whether to add it as another COM or simply put it in the C# layer. The C# (UI layer) will use both protocol concurrently to communication with two external devices.

Comment: Let me clarify a little more, there are total of 3 layers currently, UI, App and Communication. The App is coded in C# and the Communication layer is coded in C++. The communication layer is a COM dll that used by C#. New software requires to add additional features that is completely different from the current communication layer. I am debating on what to do..

Comment: My point still stands. new code should be written in C# unless it is `lower level` code (such as device drivers and such) that must be done in C++.

Comment: There are no technical hurdles here, COM is a pure interface-based object model.  You can make any implementation for the COM server, as long as it implements the same interfaces.  The language doesn't matter either, works fine in C++ or C#.  The only detail is the {guid} that the client passes to CoCreateInstance(), that nails down the specific COM server it wants to use.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel that if I create another COM object, it seems unnecessary as a C# class within the upper layer can handle it. But then I get to re-use some of the code.

There is no right answer here.  If the amount of re-use is large, then sticking to the "legacy" method of using COM may be an appropriate choice.

If you're going to reuse 5% of your code, and have to implement the vast majority of this from scratch anyways, then a simpler API (just putting everything in the C# layer) is likely a better option.

That being said, it's completely up to you and your team to determine the best way forward.  In general, using COM is going to make the overall design far more complicated, so that will need to be weighted into the cost/benefit analysis against the reusability of your existing code.

Comment: *`completely different communication object that is radically different from the existing communication object`*. Sounds like there are not much reusability possibilities.

Comment: @HighCore Yes, but the OP still distinctly mentioned that there's an opportunity for reuse.  There's not enough details to have any idea of the level of reuse available, unfortunately.

Comment: The detailed logic cannot be used, but the operation concepts are 100% reusable. Lets just say they are both objects used to communication with external device, however the protocol used are different. Do you know if there is a performance loss when using COM compared to a simple class?   Also, if I were to choose to use a class within the C# layer, I somehow break the original architecture of the software by allowing C# layer (UI layer) to have direct access to the external interface.

Comment: @user2584960 Any time you go through COM there's a performance impact.  Keeping the logic in one "domain" or the other (pure managed, or pure native) performs better than having to cross that boundary.  If you're reusing *concepts*, but not *code*, I'd say just go with C#, especially if it's going to be used entirely from the C# side.

Comment: @user2584960 `I somehow break the original architecture of the software by allowing C# layer (UI layer) to have direct access to the external interface` - Not true. You can maintain separation of concerns by coding correctly, and the "C# layer" is not necessarily a UI-only layer.

Comment: so are you recommending to write the new communication object in C# as well and classify it as being in the same level as the COM object? Thanks for your answer, its very insightful.

Comment: Let me clarify a little more, there are total of 3 layers currently, UI, App and Communication.  The App is coded in C# and the Communication layer is coded in C++. The communication layer is a COM dll that used by C#. New software requires to add additional features that is completely different from the current communication layer. I am debating on what to do..

Comment: @user2584960 If it's only going to be used from the C# layer, might as well stick to C# then.